# Update location from time to time

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I´m getting updates of my location using the below code:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", [locations lastObject]);
}
```

Everything works fine, the problem is that the updates are coming with 1 second of interval. Is there any way to make the intervals longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` on your location manager which will update events only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected. For example, it might generate a new event when the device becomes associated with a different cell tower.

**Option 2**

You can try to reduce the accuracy of monitoring.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Do not use `kCLDistanceFilterNone` as it will report every movement.

> "All movements are reported"

and set accuracy value to something among:

```
kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters 
kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer 
kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
```

Comment: Two things. The method call you mention is deprecated and, I'm not sure the OP is talking about region monitoring.

Comment: No region monitoring. Just want to update after a few hundred meters from what i learned with this thread.

Comment: @bruno yes I got it. Apologise for the mistake. Corrected my answer. Please check.

Comment: @AnindyaSengupta i´m getting constant updates with startUpdatingLocation.

Comment: Did you remove kCLDistanceFilterNone? and did you try option 1 also? [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; (removing startUpdatingLocation)

Comment: Yes, i removed. Option 1 works fine. Finding it odd that option 2 it´s constantly updating.

Comment: What did you set in the location accuracy? try setting kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters or kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the distance filter setting. `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` gives you the best data but you'll get updates almost constantly. Now unless you're building a directions/routing application this probably isn't what you want because it's not efficient.

Set the distance filter like so:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // One of several options...
```

Alternatively, as has been mentioned there is a significant change API that you can use to receive updates. These will occur less frequently by design, but you don't have much control over how often you receive the updates.

Call this method to start receiving those updates:

```
[_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]
```

Its most common to do this while your app is backgrounded.

Check the docs for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Answer (score 1):

just use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is should help also set `distanceFilter`

And of course refer to docs [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter)